# Create a subclass warning with JPA, JSF in Netbeans

Tags: jsf, jpa, netbeans

I am using Netebans 7.3 to develop a JSF application with JPA. When I create a new Entity, there is a warning at the @Entity line just above the class decleration "Create Subclass" and when I click on the it leads me to create a class with default name adding Impl suffix to the original class. Why it gives such warning and what can I do with the new subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans documentation says 'Create Subclass' is a suggestion.

http://wiki.netbeans.org/Java_Hints

It also says that it was added in version 7.2 , I guess they have not perfected it yet and it is showing up as suggestion in a few more places than required.

Comment: Thanks. It is a suggestion. I will ignore the suggestion.